# Iterate through list of houses and find comparables in MS SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, data-science, data-analysis

I have dataset of house / real estate listings along with longitude and latitude. I want to compare prices (for sale and for rent) with neighbouring listings and be able to see an average for similar houses within say 1 mile radius.

I think i need to run through a loop or a cursor?

I am running MS SQL 2019.

This is what i have tried so far:

Listings Table (simplified):

- listing_id (nvarchar)
- longitude (float)
- latitude (float)
- num_bedrooms (int)
- price (int)
- rent_or_sale (nvarchar)
- GeoLocation (geography)

I have populated the GeoLocation column based on the longitude and latitude columns.

I can get the listings within 1km using the following code which works fine (after i set the longitude and latitude manually)

```
DECLARE @Latitude float 
DECLARE @Longitude float
DECLARE @point geography
DECLARE @distance int = 1000; 

SET @Latitude = XX
SET @Longitude  = XX

SET @point = geography::Point(@Latitude, @Longitude, 4326);


SELECT listing_id, price from Listings WHERE @point.STDistance([GeoLocation]) <= @distance
AND status = 'to_rent'
```

What I want to do is iterate through all the listings in the listings table, bring back the properties within a given distance and store that into a Comparables table where i can then run averages / other calc's

Comparables Table:

- listing_id (nvarchar)
- other_listing_id (nvarchar)
- other_listing_price (int)
- other_listing_price_type (nvarchar)
- other_listing_distance (int)

I think I need to loop through all the items in the Listings table to build this?

I am trying the following code to do the loop - but it is taking a long time to run, and this is without running the distance query, just a loop through all the rows. (currently 30 mins and still not completed)

Listings table currently contains around 10k rows.

Am I on the right tracks or is there a more optimal way to run this?

```
DECLARE @CursorTestID INT = 1;
DECLARE @RunningTotal BIGINT = 0;
DECLARE @RowCnt BIGINT = 0;

-- get a count of total rows to process 
SELECT @RowCnt = COUNT(0) FROM Listings
 
WHILE @CursorTestID <= @RowCnt
BEGIN

   SELECT Listing_ID 
    FROM (
        SELECT Listing_ID, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Listing_ID) AS RowNum
        FROM Listings
    ) AS MyDerivedTable
    WHERE MyDerivedTable.RowNum = @CursorTestID



   SET @CursorTestID = @CursorTestID + 1 
 
END
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need a loop. Loops should be avoided in SQL.  Just use a simple JOIN:

e.g.

```
SELECT Lis1.Listing_ID, AVG(Lis2.price) as AvgPriceNeighborhood
FROM listings Lis1
JOIN Listings Lis2
    ON Lis2.[GeoLocation].STDistance(Lis1.[GeoLocation]) <= @distance
GROUP BY Lis1.Listing_ID
```